# WampServer 2.2a-x32 .htaccess not working

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, wamp, wampserver

i am using WampServer 2.2a-x32 and i am trying to use .htaccess file in my webroot folder.

i have rewrite.php file and here is its code

```
<h2 align=center> 
<?php 
// mod_rewrite Test Page 
if($_GET['link']==1){echo"You are not using mod_rewrite";} 
elseif($_GET['link']==2){echo"Congratulations!! You are using Apache mod_rewrite";} 
else{echo" mod_rewrte Test ";} 
?> 
</h2> 

<hr> 

<head>    
</head> 

<body> 
<p><a href="rewrite.php?link=1">LINK1</a> = rewrite.php?link=1</p>
<p><a href="link2.html">LINK2</a> = link2.html</p>     
</body> 
</html>
```

i have .htaccess file and here is its code

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^link([^/]*).html$ rewrite.php?link=$1 [L]
```

in my http.conf file i have

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so uncommented (without #)
```

and my Apache is configured to listen to 8080 port not sure if its the issue.

So if i hit the link http://localhost:8080/test/rewrite.php i get to see the page but when i hit link2 mod_rewrite doesn't seem to work. i get Not Found
The requested URL /test/link2.html was not found on this server.

My system is windows 7 x32
any suggestions ?

Comment: btw i tested also at port 80 but it is still not working

Comment: Have you tried enabeling [RewriteLogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel) to get information on what's working and what's not?

Comment: You need to specify a logfile with `RewriteLog` in the `httpd.conf` and in your `.htaccess` you can add a line that says `RewriteLogLevel 3` to specify that you want logging for this use.

Comment: What value does the [`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride) have in your config? Have you tried to set the `RewriteBase` to `/test` (okay, this is probably not the cause)? To enable `RewriteLogLevel` you have to specify a logfile with `RewriteLog` and then just set the level like `RewriteLogLevel 3` (the numeric parameter has a range from 0 to 9 where 0 is no output and 9 is log everything).

Comment: I love WAMP.  To enable the module should be as simple as right clicking on the taskbar icon, hover over apache, and find the mod_rewrite module.  Just check it and everything should be done for you.  If you still can't figure out the issue, goto your wamp install folder and view the apache error logs.  Very helpful info there.

Comment: ok guys i managed to add <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine ON
 rewritelog c:/rewrite.log
 rewritelogLevel 9
</IfModule>

Comment: this is the log file 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2011:17:38:41 +0200] [localhost/sid#a648d8][rid#2bc00b8/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /test/rewrite.php
(1) pass through /test/rewrite.php
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /test/rewrite.php
(1) pass through /test/rewrite.php
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /test/rewrite.php
(1) pass through /test/rewrite.php

Comment: in my .htaccess file i just added some junk like "asdadsa" and saved it. This should create some error? but it doesn't i am not sure that .htaccess is working yet

Comment: @themhz Did you restart the Apache service after you modified httpd.conf?

Comment: yes DaveRandom i have restarted apache. I have another hint. When i browse my directory say http://localhost/test i can see in the directory the htaccess file. This meens that apache is not handling it as it should be? isn't suposed for this file to be hidden?

Comment: ok i also found out that in windows the file .htaccess was like htaccess without the "." and i renamed it to .htaccess. Now it doesn't appear anymore in the directory listing. But is still not working.

Comment: ok guys I finally made it. 
First mistake that I was not aware of, was the name of the file htaccess. It didn't have the full stop in front .htaccess, so i managed to rename it and it worked. Thanx for your knowledge guys. I strongly suggest that people check that .htaccess and not misconfuse it with htaccess if windows seems to be hiding that "."htaccess there.

Many thanx and mary chrismas to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanx i actualy managed to fix it. The problem was that the file was not named corectly, instead of .htaccess it was htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a RewriteBase, because the htaccess in not located in the document-root.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /test
RewriteRule ^link([^/]*).html$ rewrite.php?link=$1 [L]
```